# Count from 1-10 using a loop with return values to a 10-element sized single-dimensional array

Tags: java

How to create a java application that can count from 1-10 using a looping control structure and then return values to a 10-element sized single-dimensional array?

Comment: What have you tried so far? And what exactly was the problem?

Comment: Please elaborate on the whole situation and the requirements. I don't get it. An example would be very helpful. A loop iterating `1` to `10` would be `for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) { ... }`.

Comment: any simple program that can count from 1-10 using a looping control structure and then return values to a 10-element sized single-dimensional array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Program {
 public static void main(String[] args){
     int[] numbers = new int[10];
     for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
         numbers[i]=i+1;
     }

     for (int i : numbers) {
         System.out.println(i);
     }
 }
}
```